# How to calculate count of records in map based on keys in Helper

Tags: lightning, javascript

I am getting map in helper in callback

```
action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            var wrapperRecords = response.getReturnValue();
            console.log('wrapperRecords-->',wrapperRecords);
            var wrapperMap = response.getReturnValue().retMap;
            console.log('wrapperMap-->',wrapperMap);
```

in wrapperMap I am getting values in console:

[image]

How can I get the length of records based on a key(for example to get length of records for my 1st key.

Answer (score 1):

To access a specific key, you'd use the exact same syntax as for an array, but you use a String:

```
// Output length of this key's array
console.log(wrapperMap['Product Addition to Forecast'].length);
```

You could output all the values by doing something like this:

```
Object.keys(wrapperMap).forEach(
  key => console.log(key+' has ' +wrapperMap[key].length +' record(s).'));
```